# How to merge / join two dataframes without duplicating rows and keep those with same parameters on the same row, in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I would join/merge two dataframes as these:

```
ID1 = [2002070, 2002070, 2002740,2002740,2003010]
ID2 = [2002070, 200800, 200800,2002740,2002740]
Value1 = [4.5, 4.2, 3.7, 4.8, 4.4]
Value2 = [7.2, 6.4, 10, 2.3, 1.5]
date1 = ['2008-05-14', '2005-12-07','2008-10-27', '2009-04-20', '2012-03-01']
date2 = ['2005-12-07','2003-10-10', '2004-05-14', '2011-06-03', '2015-07-05']
date1=pd.to_datetime(date1)
date2=pd.to_datetime(date2)
df1=pd.DataFrame({'ID': ID1, 'Value1': Value1, 'Date1':date1}).sort_values('Date1')
df2=pd.DataFrame({'ID': ID2, 'Value2': Value2, 'Date2':date2}).sort_values('Date2')
ok = df1.merge(df2,on='ID', how='outer', sort=True)
```

And I obtained this new df, where data are duplicated when are missing in one df

```
          ID  Value1    Date1   Value2  Date2
    0   200800  NaN     NaT     6.4 2003-10-10
    1   200800  NaN     Na      10  2004-05-14
    2   2002070 4.2 2005-12-07  7.2 2005-12-07
    3   2002070 4.5 2008-05-14  7.2 2005-12-07
    4   2002740 3.7 2008-10-27  2.3 2011-06-03
    5   2002740 3.7 2008-10-27  1.5 2015-07-05
    6   2002740 4.8 2009-04-20  2.3 2011-06-03
    7   2002740 4.8 2009-04-20  1.5 2015-07-05
    8   2003010 4.4 2012-03-01  NaN    NaT
```

But I would like to obtain this, where only data with the same ID and Date lie on the same row, the other data are replaced with NaN or NaT and not duplicated

```
         ID  Value Date1       Value2   Date2
    0   200800  NaN   NaT       6.4 2003-10-10
    1   200800  NaN   NaT       10  2004-05-14
    2   2002070 4.2 2005-12-07  7.2 2005-12-07   <---on the same row
    3   2002070 4.5 2008-05-14  NaN    NaT       <---not duplicated
    4   2002740 3.7 2008-10-27  NaN    NaT       
    5   2002740 NaN    NaT      2.3 2011-06-03
    6   2002740 NaN    NaT      1.5 2015-07-05
    7   2002740 4.8 2009-04-20  NaN    NaT
    8   2003010 4.4 2012-03-01  NaN    NaT
```

Do you know how to do?

Comment: Why is `8,9` row duplicated?

Comment: Because Date2.iloc[8] is different from Date2.iloc[9]. Thanks for the answer, I was looking for just this type of code!

Comment: hmm, so `5,6` rows are same `8,9` rows? Not understand

Comment: I have seen the error!! I will edit with the correct table. Sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) by both columns to left and right side:

```
ok = df1.merge(df2, left_on=['ID','Date1'],right_on=['ID','Date2'], how='outer', sort=True)
print (ok)
        ID  Value1      Date1  Value2      Date2
0   200800     NaN        NaT     6.4 2003-10-10
1   200800     NaN        NaT    10.0 2004-05-14
2  2002070     4.2 2005-12-07     7.2 2005-12-07
3  2002070     4.5 2008-05-14     NaN        NaT
4  2002740     3.7 2008-10-27     NaN        NaT
5  2002740     4.8 2009-04-20     NaN        NaT
6  2002740     NaN        NaT     2.3 2011-06-03
7  2002740     NaN        NaT     1.5 2015-07-05
8  2003010     4.4 2012-03-01     NaN        NaT
```